# Минимальная высота сколлбара, самопис

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

Всем привет. 
Пишу тут скрипт для  кастомного скроллбара. 
Есть проблема.

Если высота списка не очень большая, но при этом большое количество  текста в области скролла, то высота скроллбара будет очень маленькая.

Пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/ah75ryde/) <---

Пытался увеличивать его  каким то множителем.

```
    this.scroll.style.height = 
            this.scrollWrap.clientHeight * container.clientHeight / container.scrollHeight * 10 +'px';
```

Но в таком случае при скролле в самый низ,  скролл принимает не правильную позицию. Не могу понять как рассчитать коэффициент для позиционированния  скролла. 
Тот что `this.scroll.style.top`

Подскажите как правильно реализовать.

Comment: Как я понял, проблема именно с высотой ползунка? Если так, то определитесь с минимальной удобной высотой ползунка и, начиная с этой высоты, множите-делите уже не высоту, а шаг прокрутки.

Answer (score 0):

Отнял от хода ползунка разницу между высотой скролла заданную через CSS и высотой, которую считает скрипт. 
И теперь все пиксель в пиксель)

```
let scrollHeight = (scrollWrap.clientHeight * scrollVis.clientHeight / scrollVis.scrollHeight);
let scrollTop = (scrollWrap.clientHeight - 30 + scrollHeight) * scrollVis.scrollTop / scrollVis.scrollHeight;
```